# How can i close the asp.net web form pop up correctly?

Tags: asp.net

I have two web form,on the main web form have a button and in the that button write this code for open the pop up web form:

```
string url = "login.aspx";
            string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

every thing is ok,and open the pop up web form,and i write this code too close the pop up web form when i fire submit button:

```
<script>
        window.onunload = refreshParent;

    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();

    }
    </script>
```

but when fire submit button,pop up close and so open again!,how can i solve that?

Comment: This sound like classic postback problem. Could you redirect window after closing and not just reload page?

Comment: @Mino Yes i can redirect that.